# more complicate than I'm making it out to sound—"make it out to sound"?

Tags: meaning

Source: [short audio clip](http://vocaroo.com/i/s03mNlW72AjT)

Transcript:

> ...but I am sure that modern web browsers will perform these steps in parallel  and that is a lot more complicated than I'm **making it out to sound**, okay? But my bare-bones explanation here should serve as the general series of steps...

I would have no problem understanding that if he said it like this: *and that is a lot more complicated than I'm making it sound*. But that's not what he actually says. He threw an *out* in there for some reason and I don't understand why.

Comment: Look up "make out" in the dictionary. That said, the speaker isn't very bright, either.

Comment: **Making it out to be** is an idiomatic expression that means "making it appear to be".  For example, you could say, "Don't worry, the test is not as difficult as he's making it out to be."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's just a conversational filler like what one would use when being interviewed or such.

> ..a lot more complicated than I'm **making it <s>out to</s> sound**.

This should work fine, as you suggested.